# Highlighting questions with accepted answers as [solved]

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've seen this elsewhere and personally think it's a very useful feature.  When questions have an answer marked as accepted, **[solved]** gets added onto the end of the page title.  This then appears in search results on Google, etc with [solved] too.

I know it's not just me that adds the word "solved" onto the end of my searches to get quicker answers to problems.  I always jump straight to these results first as it's pretty obvious there is more chance of getting my answer from one of these links.  Just figured it might bring more people to superuser.com, etc.  Only the title would need to change, not the links to questions themselves.

Is this something that has been discussed before or could possibly be implemented at some point?  Or am I asking in completely the wrong place?

Comment: Seems nobody proposed such a thing on [metase] yet. The only problem I see with this is that not all questions are about problems that literally need to be "solved". The correct terminology would probably be "has accepted answer".

Answer (score 4):

You already know if a question is solved, because there will be a green checkmark by the accepted answer, or the search result will be a different color.

[image: checkmark]      [image: accepted box]

You can also search for questions with accepted answers using the `hasaccepted:yes` term [in the search phrase](https://superuser.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ayes).

Comment: Sorry I was probably not clear (my speciality) - I just meant from outside of superuser.com, say Google for example.  It's very clear if you're searching within superuser.com, as you very rightly say, it's just from outside if you're searching for the solution to a solved problem.

Comment: Google doesn't like when its spider sees content that humans don't.

Comment: @Eddie: I think the point is that it would show up on the title here, so Google would (properly) see it. That's the non-sneaky, standard, good way of putting a keyword in: make it so that humans clearly see it, so that Google will too.